# why does t-sql use the N prefix for nvarchar string literals?

Tags: t-sql, unicode

I understand that, in t-sql, the prefix `N` on a string literal specifies a unicode string (i.e. the type of the literal is nvarchar).  My question is:  why N?  Why not U, for Unicode, or L, like C?

Comment: `N` most likely just stands for `NVARCHAR`. What the `N` in `NVARCHAR` stands for though... :)

Comment: "national character varying"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276823%28SQL.80%29.aspx), N stands for national character.

Comment: This link is now dead, but the answer is correct.